# UV Unwrap around edges

Tags: uv

Might seem like a noobie question but I can't seem to figure it out.
What would be the most effective way to unwrap a simple cube mesh in order to replicate UV unwrap that looks like this, where an image texture extends past the edges?

Is there a simple way to do it? [image]

[image]

I've added seams to my mesh as such, but it seems that this is still not properly allowing the image to "wrap around" the edges. I'd rather not have to move the UV islands all manually. is there something I did wrong?

Making the seams on the back-side of the cube instead of the front is important, so I made sure to do that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After U > Unwrap, the UV map that is generated looks like this.

Comment: You did it the other way round! that's way it does not align. The face you mark your seams around is the one facing the wall, not the one you want to look at

Comment: @JiříHonzák Hm, seems the result is the same!

Comment: Did you unwrap it again?

Comment: @JiříHonzák yup! Cube project. I'd rather mark the seams than move the islands each time.

Comment: You cannot use cube project when marking seams! If you want to mark the seams by hand you should use unwrap

Comment: Try Unwrapping normally, you shouldn't need to do too many manual movements if the seams are done correctly! Cube project has very specific use cases, normal UVs with correct seams will work practically every time

Comment: @JiříHonzák I unwrapped it after applying all transforms but my UV doesn't seem to take on the same shape as the mesh itself :/ Why would that happen?

Comment: Could you show us the UV map @Matthew?

Comment: @JiříHonzák  Updated with new screenshots

Comment: You're going to need to scale and move the UV map by hand, this shouldn't take you long to do! It's part of UV unwrapping after all :)

Comment: In the screenshot you uploaded the seams are still on the front side? For now look here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NVeznfPXvFtmB-xr4O_Po2jlunolUm9/view?usp=share_link I'll upload it to my answer once I figure out how to compress it enough

Comment: Also the screens you uploaded clearly do not correspond to each other as it is impossible that you would have the whole seal in the picture with UVs unwrapped like this

Comment: @JiříHonzák Nope! Added them on the backside. And yes, they do correspond! I'm showing you the UV Editor with the mesh selected

Comment: @Zarbio Unfortunately this process is going to work together with a python script I've written to cycle through a folder of images, so it needs to be set once and for all!

Comment: Are you using generated in a mapping node before the texture coordinate in your material? That could be it and it's completely ignoring your UV layout. Also setting the UVs for an object then duplicating and adding new images shouldn't need you to set the UVs every single time. Good UVs hold out

Comment: You have a screenshot with the actual geometry with texture applied before the one with UV unwrapped and thats the one that does not correspond to it. If even the video I posted in the comment above does not help, then upload the image of unwrapped geometry along with the actual textured geometry that corresponds to it

Comment: Check my screen recording: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VArx8oSmOYp8Fvi_xdST2NRfiBQJHT_h?usp=share_link @JiříHonzák

Comment: Did you apply scale and rotation? (ctrl+a -> rotation & scale) Anyway besides the rotation I dont see a problem? it seems like it does exactly as it should? The scale of UV islands is different thing from the one we were discussing. It is not possible to see clearly in the video, but it look like the picture continues along the edges as it should

Comment: @JiříHonzák all transforms have been applied. Inititally the mesh has been unwrapped using "PRoject from View -- Scaled to Bounds". You'll see at the 0:27 mark what happens once I use U > Unwrap, the UV islands don't match

Comment: upload the file and I'll have a look.

Comment: Was too large for Blend Exchange, please find here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SbouPeVRpb5oYoZkcbI27uJCJk6huPWG/view?usp=share_link

The mesh in question is the "Canvas"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145286/discussion-between-jiri-honzak-and-matthew).

Answer (score 1):

In this case simple cube projection shoud be ok, you might need to move the UV islands in UV editing in order to make the image seamless. Or you can mark seams by hand like this (select edges -> right click -> mark seam):

[image]

After unwrap you get exactly what you want:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Check the updates I made to my comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to create seams at the corners and at the back of your cube to and unwrap that way, I'd set up the UVs like this: [image]

Make sure you're applying the scale before you do the unwrap so the uvs turn out right.

Bonus view of the back to help you understand where I placed my seams!
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Check the updates I made to my comment

Comment: Can you post your UV layout? Bit difficult to understand whats going on at the moment :) Just from the look of things you look like you marked the seam on the wrong side of the cube!

Answer (score 1):

If you unwrap with the default mode, here is what you'll get:

[image]

To make the UV square, enable the *Snap to Vertex* option and move the vertices until you have this:

[image]

If the sides are too deformed, subdivide a bit:

[image]